# I need help finding information on Ada 2012 (or 2005)

Tags: ada

Ok, so I am in my senior year of a CS degree and I have to write a 30ish page paper on Ada for my programming languages course.  I've found loads of info...for the 1983 version.  But I am having trouble with finding newer info.  Does anyone know where I can an introduction to programming in Ada 2012 (or at least 2005) that can be cited in a paper?

I am supposed to be able to compare and contrast the old and new and, like I said, I have books upon books worth of info on the old version, I just can't find anything on the newer version that is not about either something very specific (like concurrency) or is from a non-citeable source.  And even then, that is just for the 2005 version...

...I have not really found anything on the 2012 version at all.  I figure it may be too new.

I have searched the ACM Database, Books 24/7, My college library, and Google Scholar.

I'm not asking you guys to do my research for me or anything.  I just need a push in the right direction.  I feel like I have enough that if I could just get one or two newer sources, I could get started.

Any help at all would be really appreciated.  It looks like a fun language (if not a little overwhelming) and I am getting really worried about this project.  I still have 2 months to work on it, but this teacher is like...well...like this woman: 
http://images.wikia.com/harrypotter/images/f/f9/Dolores_Umbridge_(Promo_still_from_HP5_movie)_10-15-2009.jpg

Thanks in advance for any help.

tl;dr - I can find plenty of old info, but almost nothing recent on Ada.

Comment: LOL, after seeing that pic, I can understand your concern!

Comment: See also the [Ada tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ada/info).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried some of these pages?

[Ada Information Clearinghouse](http://www.adaic.org/ada-resources/)

[Ada2012.org](http://ada2012.org)

[Ada Core - Ada Answers](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers)

Comment: Thank you guys.  I've actually talked to the teacher since posting this and she has agreed to let me just write about the original version (on the condition that I include an extra condition that explains the major changes in each new version.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the Ada 2012 Rationale: http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-0-2.html
You probably want to check out the entries on:

- Taft amendment type
- quantified expression
- aspect
- predicate (dynamic & static)
- pre-/post-conditions
- iterator, container

Here's two pages on Ada's Protected Objects:

- http://www.iuma.ulpgc.es/users/jmiranda/gnat-rts/node25.htm
- http://jalada.co.uk/2010/02/04/adas-protected-objects.html

Also the Ada 2005 Rationale's entry on null excluding access [sub]types:
http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-3-2.html

Comment: You could also mention the Wikibook, & specifically the page on new 2012 features: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Ada_2012

Comment: Oh, you're right I forgot about that... but then again 90% of the links there are need-an-entry links, so it would be of very limited usefulness in a paper (especially because the aspects themselves don't have any summary/description).

Answer (score 1):

There is a series of articles by John Barnes in the last Ada User Journal numbers on the new features of Ada 2012. They're quite easy to read and go to the meat of the matter. I'm pretty sure they can be found in Adacore's website. Lemme google it...

OK, here are the first four chapters (links on the right):

http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/about/ada-2012

And this chart is a good at-a-glance source of terms to look for:

http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/about/ada-comparison-chart/